# Failed to access Java code from XUL/JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, xul

This is my java file :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.String; 
public class ListFiles { 
public static void main(String[] args) {

  // Directory path here
  String path = "D:/xmlfiles/";

  String files;
  File folder = new File(path);
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

  for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
      files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
      System.out.println(files);

      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my JS file :

```
function display(){

el = document.getElementById("text");
el.addEventListener("oncommand", display, true);
//loading Encryption Class

//alert('hffffi');

var myClass = cl.loadClass('ListFiles'); // use the same loader from above

var myObj = myClass.newInstance();


// Pass whatever arguments you need (they'll be auto-converted to Java form, taking into account the LiveConnect conversion rules)
var Files = myObj.String; 


alert('karthik it works'+Files);

document.getElementById("text").value=Files; 
}
```

Explanation : 
I'm trying to get the ouptput string of java into my JS. I'm able to connect JAVA with JS using Live connect in XUL Firefox. 
The problem right now, how can display the output of java in my JS file.

Thanks guys.

Comment: please correct your formatting as we can help you

Comment: I have added some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `var Files = myObj.String;` is supposed to return the output of the Java program?!

I dunno that much about LiveConnect, but I'd more expect the `ListFiles` class to have a method that returns the list. Currently it is only read into a local variable (and `main()` would not be called automatically in the LiveConnect setup anyway).

So how about something like:

```
public class ListFiles {
  public:
    String getFiles() {
       String result = "";
       // [iterate over the files and add their names to result]
       return result;
    }    
}
```

And in the JS code:

```
var Files = myObj.getFiles();
```

instead of

```
var Files = myObj.String;
```

Comment: Hi,when you put like this in JS; var Files = myObj.getFiles(); its not executing.